# Where can I find Plant Fiber and Iron?

Tags: starbound

Where can I find Plant Fiber and Iron? I'm on the planet Cephei Rim VI.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a normal planet, not radioactive, or a moon or anything unusual, is it? On asteroid fields and most moons you can't find either resource.

Answer (score 1):

Iron can be found by mining underground, and plant fiber can be found by breaking vines in caves, and by breaking foliage on the surface. Also, planets are randomly generated, so it's impossible to tell exactly where anything can be found on your planet.

Comment: Thanks, it`s legit but there`s nothing like that on my planet ;-;

Answer (score 0):

### Iron

Iron ore can be found in form of iron ore. It looks like this:

[image: background-ore][image: foreground-ore]

It can be minded with your matter manipulator in dig mode. Right-click for ore in the background and left-click for ore in the foreground. The best way to find it is by going spelunking and explore some caves. When you can't find any larger caves near your base which can be accessed from the surface, just dig down a bit and you will find some.

You also occasionally find ore in chests on the surface.

Before you can craft anything useful out of ores, you need to turn it into bars first. This is done at a *Primitive Furnace* which you build at an *Inventors Table* which you need to craft.

When you unlocked the Outpost you will also be able to buy metal bars for Pixels at the Ursa Miner shop. But it is really expensive, so it's only an option when you are very rich and very lazy.

### Plant Fiber

There are multiple sources of plant fiber. The most accessible one in the beginning are vines which are hanging from the ceilings of caves which you can cut with your matter manipulator. They are purple on my starting planet, but they can appear in many different colors.

[image: vines]

But when you want to farm a really large amount of it, you should go to a Forest planet and look for an area on the surface where huge flowers grow like trees:

[image: flower-biome]

Look for those which **don't** have petals. They drop large amounts of plant fiber when cut. Like all tree-like background objects, they also drop saplings which you can then plant near your base to create farms like this:

[image: plant fiber farm]

Felling all the plants on this screen gave me 980 units of plant matter.